# socket.Close() halting the program (java)

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sockets, tcp

I'm doing a TCP chat with Java and when I try to close a socket the client which is a jFrame window stops working (plus CPU usage spikes up).
I'm using NetBeans 8.1 with jdk1.8.0_91.

I need to close the connection and initialize it. I did some research but still couldn't find anything, am I missing something ?

### Edit

Reduced ChatThread code a lot, also deleted comments and some lines from the other .java.

Code:
Project Server, Server.java contains:

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
 import java.net.ServerSocket;
 import java.net.Socket;

 public class Server {

 private static final String version = "v0.4(Curry) 07/04/17";
 private static ServerSocket srvSocket;

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int port = -1;
    int maxConnections = 50;

    Socket[] connections = new Socket[maxConnections];
    String[] users = new String[maxConnections];

    System.out.println("Chat Server - " + version + " por Marçal");

    switch (args.length) {
        case 0:
            port = 5667;
            break;
        case 1:
            try {
                port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Uso: java -jar chatserver.jar [puerto]");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            break;
    }

    InetSocketAddress socketAddr = null;
    socketAddr = new InetSocketAddress(port);

    srvSocket = null;
    try {
        srvSocket = new ServerSocket();
        srvSocket.bind(socketAddr);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: imposible conectar");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    System.out.println("en línea, aceptando conexiones en el puerto " + port + " ...\n");

    int idSocket = 0;
    while (srvSocket != null) {
        try {
            if (connections[idSocket] == null) {

                Socket socket = srvSocket.accept();
                connections[idSocket] = socket;

                if (idSocket % 2 == 0) {
                    users[idSocket] = "John Doe " + idSocket;
                } else {
                    users[idSocket] = "Jane Doe " + idSocket;
                }
                System.out.println("Nueva conexión: id"+idSocket+" ["+connections[idSocket].getInetAddress()+":"+connections[idSocket].getPort()+"]");
                Thread t = new ChatThread(idSocket, maxConnections, connections, users[idSocket]);
                t.start();                    
            }
            idSocket = (idSocket + 1) % maxConnections;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: fallo E/S servidor");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
    srvSocket.close();}}
```

Project Server, ChatThread.java contains:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ChatThread extends Thread {

   private final int id;
   private final int maxConnections;
   private final Socket[] conns;
   private final String[] users;
   OutputStream salida;
   InputStream entrada;

public ChatThread(int idSocket, int maxConnections, Socket[] connections, String user) {
    this.maxConnections = maxConnections;
    this.id = idSocket;
    this.conns = connections;
    this.users = new String[this.maxConnections];
    this.users[this.id] = user;    
}

public void run() {
    try {
        String buff;           
        salida = conns[id].getOutputStream();
        entrada = conns[id].getInputStream();  

        salida.write("BLABLA".getBytes());

        conns[id].shutdownInput(); //No Halt
        conns[id].shutdownOutput(); //Halt
        salida.flush();  //Halt          
        salida.close(); //Halt
        entrada.close(); //Halt         
        conns[id].close(); //Halt
         } catch (IOException e) {
         }}}
```

Project Client, Client.java contains:
    package com.chat;

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;

public class Client extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static final String version = "v0.4(Curry) 07/04/17";

private JFrame frmChat;
private JTextField input;
private JTextArea salida;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;

private static InetSocketAddress socketAddr;
private static InputStream is;
private static OutputStream os;

static String text;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Client window = new Client(args);
    window.frmChat.setVisible(true);

    try {
        Socket cliSocket = new Socket();
        cliSocket.connect(socketAddr);
        window.frmChat.setTitle("Chat " + version + " - " + cliSocket.getLocalAddress().toString() + " [" + cliSocket.getLocalAddress().getCanonicalHostName() + "]");

        is = cliSocket.getInputStream();
        os = cliSocket.getOutputStream();

        window.input.requestFocusInWindow();
        byte[] msg = new byte[100];
        String str;
        text = "";
        do {
            is.read(msg);
            str = new String(msg);
            window.salida.append(str);
            msg = new byte[100];
        } while (!text.equals("SALIR"));

        cliSocket.close();
        window.frmChat.dispose();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        window.salida.setText(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public Client(String[] args) {
    int port = -1;
    switch (args.length) {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("Uso: java -jar chatclient.jar ip|host [puerto]");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        case 1:
            port = 5667;
            break;
        case 2:
            try {
                port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Error: debe especificarse un puerto");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            break;
    }

    socketAddr = null;
    try {
        socketAddr = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(args[0]), port);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: host no encontrado / sintaxis incorrecta");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    frmChat = new JFrame();
    frmChat.setTitle("Chat");
    frmChat.setResizable(false);
    frmChat.setBounds(100, 100, 441, 411);
    frmChat.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frmChat.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    salida = new JTextArea();
    salida.setEditable(false);
    salida.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 335);

    DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) salida.getCaret();
    caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(salida, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 335);
    frmChat.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

    input = new JTextField();
    input.setBounds(10, 354, 414, 20);
    frmChat.getContentPane().add(input);
    input.setColumns(100);

    input.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            text = input.getText().trim();
            try {
                if (!text.equals("") && text != null) {
                    os.write(text.getBytes());
                    os.flush();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                salida.append("Error: no se puede enviar");
            }
            input.setText(null);
        }});}}
```

### Edit

I found the mistake, it was in the while loop that we're not supposed to modify... it was checking if the connection was closed in the wrong way.

Comment: I'm taking it that your Swing GUI is freezing, suggesting that your code is not following Swing threading rules. I'm not sure about others, but I would need to see more code, as close to a [mcve] as you could produce, and as always small enough to post with your question as code-formatted text, but large enough to show us the problem.

Comment: What exception was thrown?

Comment: No exception that I'm aware of, only the Swing GUI freezing and CPU usage spiking making any client unable to keep writing in it.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem manifests here...

```
do {
    is.read(msg);
    str = new String(msg);
    window.salida.append(str);
    msg = new byte[100];
} while (!text.equals("SALIR"));
```

You're not paying attention to what is been returned by `is.read`.  This will return `-1` after the socket is closed at the server end, meaning it's reached the "end of file" or there is no more content to be read.

Because you're basically ignoring it, the `do-while` loop is free to run as fast as it can, basically consuming the CPU cycles and rendering the client useless.

It's important to pay attention to the number of bytes read from the socket, as it will indicate two things, 1- When there is nothing left to read and 2- How much content is available in your array.  This means you can reuse the array on each iteration, something like...

```
int read = -1;
while ((read = is.read(msg)) != -1) {
    str = new String(msg, 0, read);
    if (str.equals("SALIR")) {
        break;
    }
    window.salida.append(str);
}
```

Now, as soon as you add this to your code, the frame will flash up and disappear, because you've closed the socket at the server end.

Typically, you'd have some kind of loop in the server thread which was reading/writing content and which would only exit when you send it the "exit" command, meaning that your client `while-loop` wouldn't exit after the first message is read, but I'm guessing this is you just starting to play around.

Now, having said all that, your client code is violating the single threaded nature of Swing, see [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

There are a number of ways you might fix this, but `SwingWorker` is probably among the simplest, see [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes i have a loop in the server thread that reads/writes and should exits on "exit" word. Also tried your code and works as u say but in this case the content of the client should not be modified... so I may be missing something in the server part which causes a continuous -1 spam from the client side. I'll keep trying in the next days and update if anything new comes up :)

Comment: Based on the example code, your server doesn't have a read/write loop, it writes a message and then closes the streams and socket